# hyphen resources in rails 3 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How is it possible to use hyphen in resources urls?
For example: `/my-model/` or `/my-model/1`.
If I define route as `resources :"my-model"` I get syntax error because rails generates method `def hash_for_my-models_url(options = nil)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Ruby on Rails Routing I Would Like to Use Dash \`-\` Instead of Underscore \`\_\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334465/in-ruby-on-rails-routing-i-would-like-to-use-dash-instead-of-underscore)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
  resources "my-models", :as => :my_models, :controller => :my_models
```

**UPDATE:**
As Timo Saloranta said in comment it works without `:controller => :my_models` in latest Rails 3 versions.

Comment: I think this works too (difference would be in the naming of route helpers): `resources :product_types, :path => '/product-types'`

Comment: It works without the **controller** part with the latest Rails 3 versions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:as` option to configure resourceful routes with hyphenated URLs:

```
map.resources :my_model, :as => "my-model"
```

results in

```
my_model_index GET /my-model(.:format) {:action=>"index",
  :controller=>"my_model"}
```

...etc...

Comment: I have already tred to do this. I get the same error as when I am using hyphen-named model.

Comment: Even when you use a quoted string instead of a symbol?

Comment: I have found the solution. You can see it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a custom route?

```
map.connect "/my-model/:id", :controller => 'my-model-controller', :action => 'read'
```

This would invoke the 'read' method of 'my-model-controller.rb'.

Comment: Yes it is obvious solution but It is interesting how is it possible to define hyphen routes using resources.