# Routes with Dash `-` Instead of Underscore `_` in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

I want my urls to use dash `-` instead of underscore `_` as word separators. For example `controller/my-action` instead of `controller/my_action`.

I'm surprised about two things:

1. Google et al. continue to distinguish them.
2. That Ruby on Rails doesn't have a simple, global configuration parameter to map `-` to `_` in the routing. Or does it?

The best solution I've is to use `:as` or a named route.

My idea is to modify the Rails routing to check for that global config and change `-` to `_` before dispatching to a controller action.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I also prefer dashes to underscores in urls (as well as in html/css element ids, names, and classes), but I haven't tried to implement it. I would migrate to rails 3 first and then worry about this because rails 3 has a lot of drastic upgrades to middleware and routing.

Comment: Thanks Justice. I'll hold off until I upgrade and get familiar with v3.

Comment: See this article about **[Hyphenated Routes in Rails](https://hired.com/blog/candidates/hyphenated-routes-rails/)**

Answer (score 84, accepted):

With Rails 3 and later you can do like this:

```
resources :user_bundles, :path => '/user-bundles'
```

---

Another option is to modify Rails, via an initializer.
I don't recommend this though, since it may break in future versions (edit: doesn't work in Rails 5).

Using `:path` as shown above is better.

```
# Using private APIs is not recommended and may break in future Rails versions.
# https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1012
#
# config/initializers/adjust-route-paths.rb
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    class Mapper
      module Resources
        class Resource
          def path
            @path.dasherize
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I am brand new to Rails. What file would you add a line like this into?

Comment: there has to be a better and faster way to convert all routes that has undersore to hyphens

Comment: @carbonr how about the example I just added? :)

Comment: @sandstrom thats it! sweet!

Comment: Sadly this monkey patch no longer works in Rails 5.  This will dasherize everything except #index and #create, which will remain as underscore and create nasty bugs.  If anyone has an updated script for Rails 5, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can overload controller and action names to use dashes:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :my_resources, path: 'my-resources' do
  collection do
    get 'my-method', to: :my_method
  end
end
```

You can test in console:

```
rails routes -g my_resources
my_method_my_resources GET  /my-resources/my-method(.:format) my_resources#my_method
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use named routes.  It will allow using '-' as word seperators.  In routes.rb,

```rb
map.name_of_route     'a-b-c',       :controller => 'my_controller', :action => "my_action"
```

Now urls like http://my_application/a-b-c would go to specified controller and action.

Also, for creating dynamic urls

```rb
map.name_of_route    'id1-:id2-:id3',       :controller => 'my_controller', :action => "my_action"
```

in this case 'id1, id2 & id2 would be passed as http params to the action

In you actions and views,

```rb
name_of_route_url(:id1=>val1, :id2=>val2, :id3=>val3)
```

would evaluate to url 'http://my_application/val1-val2-val3'.

Comment: I want to avoid the manual maintenance of the routing, so named routes are out. I just want rails routing do the replacement for me wholesale and keep my config files tight.

Answer (score 2):

if you use underscores in a controller and view file then just use dashes in your routes file, and it will work..

get 'blog/example-text' this is my route for this controller

def example_text
end  <-- this is my controller

and example_text.html.erb is the file

and this is the actual link site.com/blog/example-text

i figured this is works for me, and it's more effective than underscores SEO wise