# Rails 4 - how to use hyphen in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to figure out the right way to use hyphens in Rails 4 view.  If I create a controller view like this:

```
rails generate controller admin client_new
```

How then do I get the correct route output as:

```
http://www.website.com/admin/client-new
```

This is probably so basic, but I can't find the right doc's to support this.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you mean http://www.website.com/admin/client_new with underscore?

Comment: no, the view is client_new.html.erb, but I want the url architecture to change the underscore to the hyphen.

Comment: Have you tried get "admin/client-new", to: "admin#client_new"?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7798131/1380867 `resources :user_bundles, :path => '/user-bundles'` I think that this post will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have action for this `client_new.html.erb` in some controller, then simply map it manually:

```
get '/admin/client-new', to: 'controller#action'
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually map the routes in the routes.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

Your route would need to be explicitly set to point to the proper controller.  Something like:

```
get '/admin/client-new', to: "admin/client_new#index"
```

This will perform the `index` method on `Admin::ClientNewController` when a GET is performed on `/admin/client-new`