# Rails dasherize routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to have all my Rails routes treat dasherized paths as equivalent to underscored paths.

i.e. navigating to `/foo-bars` and `/foo_bars` both trigger the route `resources :foo_bars`.

Is that possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334465/routes-with-dash-instead-of-underscore-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 1):

will this help.

```
type_regexp = Regexp.new(["foo_bars", "foo-bars"].join("|"))
resources "foo_bars", path: type_regexp
```

if you have routes other than REST do this

```
resources "foo_bars", path: type_regexp do 
 member do 
  .....
 end
 collection do
  .....
 end
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that will apply to all routes automatically

Comment: i think Rails do not provide any normal/easy way to do it for all routes. what ever i have searched and implemented. this case will be handled explicitly. but if some one has some better solution. i would be glad to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Just define Athar's answer as a lambda should be good enough IMHO.
Something like this:

```
custom_resources = ->(route_name) {
  string_route_name = route_name.to_s
  underscore_route_name = string_route_name.underscore
  dasherized_route_name = string_route_name.dasherize
  path_regexp = Regexp.new([
    Regexp.escape(underscore_route_name),
    Regexp.escape(dasherized_route_name),
  ].join('|'))
  # more custom code here if desired
  resources underscore_route_name, path: path_regexp
}

custom_resources.call(:foo_bar)
custom_resources.call(:another_foo_bar)
```

Warning: not actually tested